# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Начал писать предложение и засомневался: "...винил себя в том, что не смог спасти жизнь ребенка" или "ребенку"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта правильны. Все зависит от подчинения. Грубо говоря, словосочетание "жизнь ребенка" прикрепляется к глаголу "спасти", получается "спасти (что?) жизнь ребенка". Но может быть и такое подчинение, когда оба существительных зависят от глагола: спасти (что?) жизнь, спасти (кому?) ребенку, получаем  "спасти жизнь ребенку".

Comment: Скорее, не спасти (кому?), а жизнь (чью?) ребенка - несогласованное определение.

Comment: Согласен. Объяснение действительно тяжеловесное, но по сути правильно. Оба варианта допустимы.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: "...спасти ЧТО(жизнь) КОМУ(ребёнку)."

Comment: По аналогии с "Он спас мне жизнь" или "Он спас жизнь моему другу/ ребёнку". Сравните с другим рядом: он спас жизнь ребёнка, он спас жизнь мужчины, он спас жизнь женщины - отдаёт отчуждением от человека.